Installing langchain-together Could not build wheels for thinc, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
 building 'thinc.backends.linalg' extension
211.3             creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
211.3             creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/thinc
211.3             creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/thinc/backends
211.3             gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-env-aruim4hq/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c thinc/backends/linalg.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/thinc/backends/linalg.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
211.3             error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
211.3             [end of output]
211.3       
211.3         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
211.3         ERROR: Failed building wheel for thinc
211.3       Failed to build thinc
211.3       ERROR: Could not build wheels for thinc, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
211.3       [end of output]
211.3   
211.3   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
211.3 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
211.3 
211.3 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
211.3 │ exit code: 1
211.3 ╰─> See above for output.

This is the error am facing while pip installing langchain-together in my docker environment. OS used is Ubuntu.
I faced the same error while installing langchain-groq but for some reason when i changed it to langchain_groq(underdscore) the error perished, how do i tackle this?
I tried
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
(gcc error) did not work
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
(upgraded pip did not work)
